# Getting an "undefined: distance" error from Go compiler

Tags: go

I'm a seasoned "old school" programmer, but a rank beginner with Go. I'm making my way through the "CreateSpace: An Introduction to 
Programing in Go" book.  On p. 111, the third of Chapter 9's Chapter Problems, the task is to add a new method to the user-defined Shape interface.  The interface has been built up over the course of the chapter and here's what I have so far:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
)

type Shape interface {
    area() float64
    perimeter() float64
}

type Distance struct {
    x1, y1, x2, y2 float64
}

func (d *Distance) distance() float64 {
    a := d.x2 - d.x1
    b := d.y2 - d.y1
    return math.Sqrt(a*a + b*b)
}

type Rectangle struct {
    x1, y1, x2, y2 float64
}

func (r *Rectangle) area() float64 {
    l := distance(r.x1, r.y1, r.x2, r.y1)
    w := distance(r.x1, r.y1, r.x1, r.y2)
    return l * w
}

type Circle struct {
    x, y, r float64
}

func (c *Circle) area() float64 {
    return math.Pi * c.r * c.r
}

type Perimeter struct {
    x1, y1, x2, y2 float64
}

func (p *Perimeter) perimeter() float64 {
    s1 := distance(p.x1, p.y1, p.x1, p.y2)
    s2 := distance(p.x1, p.y2, p.x2, p.y2)
    s3 := distance(p.x2, p.y2, p.x2, p.y1)
    s4 := distance(p.x2, p.y1, p.x1, p.y1)
    return s1 + s2 + s3 + s4
}

func main() {
    d := new(Distance)
    d.x2, d.y2, d.x1, d.y1 = 0, 0, 10, 10

    p := new(Perimeter)
    p.x1, p.y1 = 0, 0
    p.x2, p.y2 = 10, 10
    fmt.Println(p.perimeter())

    r := new(Rectangle)
    r.x1, r.y1 = 0, 0
    r.x2, r.y2 = 10, 10
    fmt.Println(r.area())

    c := Circle{0, 0, 5}
    fmt.Println(c.area())

}
```

The problem is that I am getting the following error (from the compiler?):

```
user@pc /c/Go/src/golang-book/chapter9/chapterProblems
$ go run interface.go
# command-line-arguments
.\interface.go:25: undefined: distance
.\interface.go:26: undefined: distance
.\interface.go:42: undefined: distance
.\interface.go:43: undefined: distance
.\interface.go:44: undefined: distance
.\interface.go:45: undefined: distance
```

I've spent a good amount of time doing my "due diligence" hereto pertaining by rereading the chapter text and thinking hard about what this 
"undefined: distance" error might mean, but so far to no avail.
As you can see, I have defined a "Distance struct", created a new() instance of 
it called `d`, initialized its fields with the `.` operator, and created a `distance()` func, but, clearly, I'm not grokking some relevant piece(s) of information.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have a function called `distance`. It's a method of the type `*Distance`. You need to create a `*Distance` first, and then call the method.

```
d := &Distance{r.x1, r.y1, r.x2, r.y1}
l := d.distance()
```

I'd suggest starting with [Effective Go](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html). It's a very good introduction into the language for  "a seasoned programmer".

Comment: Um, does not this distance() func I created on on lines 14 through 18, not count?  Also, I'll check out "Effective Go".  Thanks

Comment: No, it's a method. `func distance(x1, y1, x2, y2 float64) float64 { ... }` - this would be a function.

Comment: Okay, I'm going back to think about this again.  I'll reply when I've come to my senses a bit more.  (:>)  Thanks, @Ainar-G

Answer (score 1):

Your function defined here:

```
func (d *Distance) distance() float64 {
    a := d.x2 - d.x1
    b := d.y2 - d.y1
    return math.Sqrt(a*a + b*b)
}
```

is a method on the Distance object. It looks like you're trying to create a new Distance instance here:

```
func (r *Rectangle) area() float64 {
    l := distance(r.x1, r.y1, r.x2, r.y1)
    w := distance(r.x1, r.y1, r.x1, r.y2)
    return l.distance() * w.distance()
}
```

but what you're actually doing is trying to call a function called `distance`.

You want

```
func (r *Rectangle) area() float64 {
    l := &Distance{r.x1, r.y1, r.x2, r.y1}
    w := &Distance{r.x1, r.y1, r.x1, r.y2}
    return l.distance() * w.distance()
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Ainar-G!  Who says you can't teach an old dog new tricks?  (:>)

Comment: If your question is resolved, please consider selecting an answer David.

Answer (score 1):

thanks @Ainar-G and @Momer!  After I got my "mind right" (had to fix a couple more self-inflicted syntax errors), the following worked:

```
<pre><code>
package main

import ("fmt"; "math")

type Shape interface {
    area() float64
    perimeter() float64
}

type Distance struct {
    x1, y1, x2, y2 float64
}

func distance(x1, y1, x2, y2 float64) float64 {
    a := x2 - x1
    b := y2 - y1
    return math.Sqrt(a*a + b*b)
}

type Rectangle struct {
    x1, y1, x2, y2 float64
}

func (r *Rectangle) area() float64 {
    l  := distance(r.x1, r.y1, r.x2, r.y1)
    w := distance(r.x1, r.y1, r.x1, r.y2)
    return l * w
}
type Circle struct {
    x, y, r float64
}

func (c *Circle) area() float64 {
    return math.Pi * c.r*c.r
}

type Perimeter struct {
    x1, y1, x2, y2 float64
}

func (p *Perimeter) perimeter() float64 {
    s1 := distance(p.x1, p.y1, p.x1, p.y2)
    s2 := distance(p.x1, p.y2, p.x2, p.y2)
    s3 := distance(p.x2, p.y2, p.x2, p.y1)
    s4 := distance(p.x2, p.y1, p.x1, p.y1)
    return s1 + s2 + s3 + s4
}

func main() {
    d := new(Distance)
    d.x1, d.y1, d.x2, d.y2 = 0, 0, 10, 10

    p := new(Perimeter)
    p.x1, p.y1, p.x2, p.y2 = 0, 0, 10, 10
    fmt.Println(p.perimeter())

    r := new(Rectangle)
    r.x1, r.y1 = 0, 0
    r.x2, r.y2 = 10, 10
    fmt.Println(r.area())

    c := new(Circle)
    c.x, c.y, c.r = 0, 0, 5
    fmt.Println(c.area())

}
<pre><code>
```

Here's the resulting output:

```
<pre><code>
David Bailey@DAVIDBAILEY-PC /c/Go/src/golang-book/chapter9/chapterProblems
$ go run interface.go
40
100
78.53981633974483

David Bailey@DAVIDBAILEY-PC /c/Go/src/golang-book/chapter9/chapterProblems
$
<pre><code>
```

Again, thank you.

Comment: You've made the *exact* same code formatting mistakes you did in the question (since corrected by others). **Look at the preview** and correct things (like the `<pre><code>` mistakes) **before** posting.

Comment: Okay.  Mea culpa.  I shall endeavor to to it correctly going forward.  Thanks.